# Batch delete files recursively in folder containing some specific text

Tags: batch-file

I would like to loop recursively over a set of folders and delete all files in those folders containing "OUT" in their name. In the example below only the files in folders folder1out and folder3out should be deleted.
E.g.:

```
root
    folder1
    folder1out
        file1
        file2
    folder2
        folder3
            file1
        folder3out
            file1
            file2
```

This is what I have by now:

```
cd root
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s') do (
    %%f|findstr /i OUT > nul:
    IF %errorlevel% == 0 (
        cd %%f
        del .
    )
)
```

But this gives me the error 'nameofthefolderin%%f' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong or if there's a better way to do this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first two lines seem OK.

Problem is with the rest.

```
%%f|findstr /i OUT > nul:
```

Um, no You need to `ECHO` the filename into `FINDSTR`
and the target string `"OUT"` should be quoted
and the colon after `NUL` isn't necessary or usual - but harmless.

```
ECHO %%f|findstr /i "OUT" > nul
```

---

```
IF %errorlevel% == 0 (
```

Common error. When the **LOGICAL** command is parsed (and that means from the `FOR` through to its closing parenthesis 6 lines later,) ANY %var% is replaced with the then-current value of %var% and THEN the command is executed on the result. Consequently, %ERRORLEVEL% would be replaced by the value of ERRORLEVEL at PARSE-TIME.

You need to use the original `IF ERRORLEVEL` form, `"IF ERRORLEVEL n"` which means *"If the errorlevel is n OR GREATER THAN n"* This form examines the CURRENT (ie. RUN-TIME) value of ERRORLEVEL.

```
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
```

(ie. if errorlevel is not (1 or greater than 1) )

---

```
    cd %%f
```

Yup, that'll work. Problem is that you'll land up setting %%f as the current directory. Might seem to be what you want, but...

```
    del .
```

Er, no - that'll try to delete all of the files in the current directory and requires a response.

You're searching for

```
RD .
```

BUT you can't delete your current directory.

So - what to do?

Simple

```
RD %%f /S /Q
```

Which should remove the directory %%f AND its subdirectories (/s) AND without prompting for authority (/Q)

**`BUT PLEASE INSERT AN ECHO BEFORE THIS COMMAND FOR TESTING`** so that the proposed delete is shown rather than EXECUTED (in case of errors...)

```
ECHO RD %%f /S /Q
```

---

So your revised batch becomes

```
cd root
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s') do (
 ECHO %%f|findstr /i "OUT" > nul
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 ECHO RD %%f /S /Q
 )
)
```

Which can be more simply done by using

```
cd root
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b /s *OUT*') do (
 ECHO RD %%f /S /Q
)
```

And one last issue may be that it's possible that you wish to delete a `*OUT*` subdirectory whit itself contains a `*OUT*` subdirectory. Because of the way FOR works, you may find that when you come to the lower-down directory, the higher hirectory has already been deleted and hence the lower directory won't exist and you get an ugly eror message.

Appending `2>NUL` to the RD command should suppress that error message

Comment: Thank you, this is allmost completely what I need except that in my case I don't want to delete the directory, I want to empty its contents. How should I do this without using CD?

Comment: change the `RD...` to `DEL /Q %%f\.` The /Q switch goes ahead and deletes the files without prompting. Add /S to delete in all subdirectories as well. Add /F to delete read-only files. `**BUT REMEMBER TO INCLUDE THE ECHO DURING TESTING!**`

Comment: Thanks, I did it with CD and than DEL but your way also works.

Answer (score 0):

With `%%f|findstr /i OUT > nul:` you're trying to execute a command %%f (which is a folder name coming from the FOR loop) so it's saying it's not recognized as a command. Because it isn't.

You need a proper way to detect 'out' in the dir name. You can get the last 3 chars of a variable using this kind of syntax :
`%%f:~-3%`
so try :
`if /i "%%f:~-3%"=="out" ...`